# Entity Framework, Code First Data Annotations - validate if field input is in a list of string values (VB)

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, code-first, data-annotations

I am using Visual Studio 2013 Express for Web (Visual Basic),
 learning to use "Entity Framework Code first" to describe the classes and generate the database.
On a string field (one character long), I have a validation like this:

```
<Display(Name:="Up/Down"),
StringLength(1, ErrorMessage:="Insert 'U' or 'D'")>
Public Property UpDown As String
```

I would like to add a Data Annotations rule to validate the string
and generate an error if not "U" or "D".
Something like:

```
In("U","D")
```

Is there a syntax to achieve this?

Thank you very much

Comment: Sounds like you'd be better off using an enumeration here.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with the `RegularExpression` attribute :

```
<RegularExpression("^U|D$")>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! In fact, there is a small error, the regular expression should be "^U|$D" (Dollar sign before the "D", not after).
Thanks again.

Comment: @user3909552 Oh in this case should be `^(U|D)$`. I thought `|` would have precedence, but seems like I was wrong. :)

Comment: I'm just learning code first now, but I think you can create an enum value and use specify that as the property type.